# Apt is not working due to unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I know that this problem is talked about on ask ubuntu many times but I still failed to solve it with the solutions I have met.

Output of `sudo apt-get purge calibre` is:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 click : Depends: python3-click-package (= 0.4.43+16.04.20160203-0ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Any other `apt` command will lead to "unmet dependencies" error. The methods mentioned in [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/q/140246): `sudo apt-get -f install` or `sudo dpkg --configure -a` or removing ppa didn't help.

My `/etc/apt/sources.list` is:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-MATE 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.1)]/ xenial main multiverse restricted  universe
deb-src http://ftp.cuhk.edu.hk/pub/Linux/ubuntu/ xenial main multiverse restricted universe #Added by   software-properties

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ftp.cuhk.edu.hk/pub/Linux/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://ftp.cuhk.edu.hk/pub/Linux/ubuntu/ xenial restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ftp.cuhk.edu.hk/pub/Linux/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ftp.cuhk.edu.hk/pub/Linux/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe restricted main multiverse #Added by   software-properties

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security
## team.
deb http://ftp.cuhk.edu.hk/pub/Linux/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://hk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://ftp.cuhk.edu.hk/pub/Linux/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://hk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ftp.cuhk.edu.hk/pub/Linux/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://hk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://ftp.cuhk.edu.hk/pub/Linux/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://hk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ftp.cuhk.edu.hk/pub/Linux/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ftp.cuhk.edu.hk/pub/Linux/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse #Added by     software-properties

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://ftp.cuhk.edu.hk/pub/Linux/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted
deb-src http://ftp.cuhk.edu.hk/pub/Linux/ubuntu/ xenial-security universe restricted main multiverse #Added by  software-properties
deb http://ftp.cuhk.edu.hk/pub/Linux/ubuntu/ xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://ftp.cuhk.edu.hk/pub/Linux/ubuntu/ xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

My `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/accessibility-dev/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/accessibility-dev/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/accessibility-dev/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/accessibility-dev/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/flexiondotorg/hal-flash/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/flexiondotorg/hal-flash/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/flexiondotorg/hal-flash/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/flexiondotorg/hal-flash/ubuntu xenial main
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/js-reynaud/kicad-4/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/js-reynaud/kicad-4/ubuntu xenial main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/js-reynaud/kicad-4/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/js-reynaud/kicad-4/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/moka/daily/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/moka/daily/ubuntu xenial main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/moka/daily/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/moka/daily/ubuntu xenial main
# deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_16.04/ /
# deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_16.04/ /
# deb http://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_16.04/ /
# deb http://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_16.04/ /
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/plushuang-tw/uget-stable/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/plushuang-tw/uget-stable/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/plushuang-tw/uget-stable/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/plushuang-tw/uget-stable/ubuntu xenial main
# deb https://dl.ring.cx/ring-nightly/ubuntu_16.04/ ring main
# deb https://dl.ring.cx/ring-nightly/ubuntu_16.04/ ring main
# deb http://archive.ubuntukylin.com:10006/ubuntukylin trusty main
# deb http://archive.ubuntukylin.com:10006/ubuntukylin trusty main
deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/stellarium/stellarium-releases/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/stellarium/stellarium-releases/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/stellarium/stellarium-releases/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/stellarium/stellarium-releases/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mate-dev/welcome/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mate-dev/welcome/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mate-dev/welcome/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mate-dev/welcome/ubuntu xenial main
```

Output of `apt-cache policy python3-click-package` is

```
python3-click-package:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.4.43+16.04.20160203-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
     0.4.43+16.04.20160203-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://hk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Please anyone help me bring my ubuntu back??

Comment: Did you try `apt-get update`
? What's the output of `apt-cache policy python3-click-package`?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `/etc/hosts` to see if you had the correct local address and private ip address (if you are not running dhcp on this system).

But if you are running dhcp, then

```
sudo /usr/sbin/dhclient eth0
 ## eth0 or the name of your interface
```

It needs to resolve itself first before the system could begin to proceed downloading.  Hopefully you would have a break from this point:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean ## discards any saved pkgs and start off with fresh ones
sudo dkpg -r calibre
sudo dkpg -r python3-click-package
sudo apt-get remove --purge calibre
sudo apt-get remove --purge python3-click-package
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo apt-get build-dep python3-click-package
sudo apt-get install python3-click-package
sudo apt-get build-dep calbire
sudo apt-get install calbire
```

finally, this probably is overkill and unnecessary, but I have found that it's helpful in some situations when i have the difficulty in engingeering the system with apt-get repository, but, who knows.  Besides, no harm in being "sure than sorry".

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
```

I rarely found myself in the position in proceeding to next "last resort" but, it did serve me well every time by doing it in old-fashioned way.

```
sudo aptitude
```

And press `g` to fetch the dependencies and scan for the rest of others' dependency requirements, then press `u` to update the system, then finally; `ctrl-c` (or `ctrl-x` ?? ) to exit aptitude and reboot.

Hopefully you will find your baby Ubuntu looking for you from this point. ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I did changed my hosts file once and forgot to restore it... Here is what I just did. I restore my hosts file, and I reboot my computer, and I `sudo apt-get autoclean` which is ok, and I `sudo dpkg -r calibre` and it seems calibre was successfully removed, and `sudo dpkg -r python3-click-package` told me it wasn't installed. Following `apt` commands gave me old results which are "The following packages have unmet dependencies". **Apt is still broken.** Do you need any more information that may help you understand the situation?